# jQuery - Find next select element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

What I am trying to do is populate data in a select element. I'm using the following code, where a user selects a SubjectCategory from one drop down, which then should populate the next select element's html. The handler itself is working just fine, it returns the correct html I need to place inside the select element.

Also, keep in mind that I eventually clone both of these select elements and will need to populate them accordingly.

The problem is that `$elem` is always returning null.

I'm guessing that it's a problem with this line of code, however not quite sure (keeping in mind that I'm also cloning these two select elements):

`var $elem = $this.closest('div').prev().find('select');`

```
$(".SubjectCategory").live("click", function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $elem = $this.closest('div').next().find('select');
    var a = $this.val();

    $.get("/userControls/BookSubjectHandler.ashx?category=" + a, {}, function (data) {
        $elem.html(data);
    });
});

<div class="singleField subjectField">
  <label id="Category" class="fieldSml">Subject Matter</label>
  <div class="bookDetails ddl"><select id="ddlSubjectMatter" class="fieldSml SubjectCategory"></select></div>

  <label id="Subjects" class="fieldSml">Category</label> 
  <div class="bookDetails ddl" id="subjectMatter"><select id="ddlSubjects" class="fieldSml Subjects"></select></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Congratulations! That is definitely some code, now what's the actual question?

Comment: @AlastairPitts: Uh, `$elem` is always returning null?

Comment: excellent editing. Just remember, it's bloody hard to answer a question if one is never asked.

Comment: @AlastairPitts: Point taken. Did you mean "problem" instead of "question"? :)

Comment: Possibly. Apologies if I offended, but I was/am frustrated with the number of questions posted that actually don't ask any question at all.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're searching inside the `<label>`, not the next `<div>` as you want. `next` only gets one element after the current one.

Try this: It searches for the first div next to your parent element.

```
var $elem = $this.closest('div').nextAll('div').first().find('select');
```

Answer (score 2):

Given that the source element has an id of *ddlSubjectMatter* and the target select element has an id of *subjectMatter*, it may be a lot simpler to capitalise the first letter of the second id (i.e. make *SubjectMatter*) then you get the second element by:

```
var elem = document.getElementById(this.id.replace(/^ddl/,''));
```

It makes the element relationship independent of the document layout.

Incidentally, it is invalid HTML to have select elements with no options, not that it is a big issue.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you creating an extraneous `$this` variable? Unless you've omitted code that requires it for a different scope, just call $(this). That might be causing the problem, too.

Comment: Nah, $this is caching $(this), which is fine since it's using it twice.

Comment: Ah so. From a quick search it looks like it is indeed fine. You learn something new every day!

Comment: It's not `$this` that's causing the problem, unfortunately.

Comment: Everytime you use `$(this)` you force jQuery to do a lookup on that element.  The `$this` allows you to only have to access the DOM once for the look up.  A growing convention is to prepend the $ to know later that `this` is actually a jQuery object and can be acted upon as such.